# Send pings in the background - Am I doing it right?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

First let me explain the app: There is a big list of http servers, that when pinged, reply with a response. The latest response and everything else about the server is kept in a database.

I've got the pinging and handling of the responses down to a fine art - I just want to know how I should setup my automated pinging service.

Currently I have setup a service (Just Service, not IntentService) which is sticky and triggers a thread (Just thread, not handler or asynctask) to be called, that has an infinite loop - in this loop I have a Thread.sleep(time) command, where time can be defined by the user, and is read from shared preferences every time the loop is repeated. Sometimes this thread can be sleeping for 24H.

After reading online, I seem to think that this sort of pausing of a thread is not a good idea and rather I should be scheduling the thread to trigger somehow. I need this pinging to remain on, and not cleared by Android. From what I have asked before, the thread will not be stopped by Android, but I still don't believe I should be telling a thread to sleep for 24 hours. So although I'm pretty sure that the timing of my pings will be accurate, I don't think this is the way to do it.

I wouldn't know how to schedule these tasks so that they would remain consistent with the user's timing and not cleared by android (Possibly with Broadcasts and receivers?), whilst also not cause a thread to hang. But if someone could tell me that what I'm doing is wrong, then I'll go do some more research.

From what I can gather, a similar system of how instant messengers check to see if you have a new message to read, works in a similar fashion. However, after looking for instant messenger guides, they either make the threads hang, or have some third party api's to handle it from them, where they just call a 'onMessageReceived' method, and handle everything in there.

TL;DR - What is the best practise to have an infinite loop off the UI thread that needs to be delayed for long periods of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an AlarmManager for a specific time like 30m, 45m, or whatever works for your case. This way you dont need to run thread or anything on background.

See Smack's [ServerPingWithAlarmManager.class](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/smack-android-extensions/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smackx/ping/android/ServerPingWithAlarmManager.java) description as it recommends the same.

```
/**
 * Send automatic server pings with the help of {@link AlarmManager}.
 * <p>
 * Smack's {@link PingManager} uses a <code>ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor</code> to schedule the
 * automatic server pings, but on Android, those scheduled pings are not reliable. This is because
 * the Android device may go into deep sleep where the system will not continue to run this causes
 * <ul>
 * <li>the system time to not move forward, which means that the time spent in deep sleep is not
 * counted towards the scheduled delay time</li>
 * <li>the scheduled Runnable is not run while the system is in deep sleep.</li>
 * </ul>
 * That is the reason Android comes with an API to schedule those tasks: AlarmManager. Which this
 * class uses to determine every 30 minutes if a server ping is necessary. The interval of 30
 * minutes is the ideal trade-off between reliability and low resource (battery) consumption.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * In order to use this class you need to call {@link #onCreate(Context)} <b>once</b>, for example
 * in the <code>onCreate()</code> method of your Service holding the XMPPConnection. And to avoid
 * leaking any resources, you should call {@link #onDestroy()} when you no longer need any of its
 * functionality.
 * </p>
 */
```

Comment: Yeah this looks like what I'm looking for. I'll look into Alarm Managers then. Thankyou for the example! Where did you find it, may I ask? :P

Comment: There is a hyperlink in the ServerPingWithAlarmManager.class click it in the answer.